# Using single quotes more than once in xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, spring

I need to edit an xml file called `activemq.xml`. I will include the xml portion, my PYTHON code snippet, and the changes I need to make.

The XML file

```xml
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

The python code snippet , It will as a task inside a shell script (linux)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace('','http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans')
ET.register_namespace('','http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core')

mytree = ET.parse('activemq.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()
elemList = list(myroot[2])
up = elemList[2]
up[0].attrib['directory'] = '/nfs'
mytree.write("activemqbak.xml")
```

The changes i need to do is to the

```xml
<persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

from `$activemqdata` to `/nfs` (my code already does this.)

My PROBLEM, however, is after modifying my xml file I am unable to perserve the namespaces as they are. I cannot make ANY changes to the xml beside modifying key-values and adding more code but not to the original tags or elements themselves.

Output example of my `tree.write` command

```xml
<ns0:beans xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:ns0="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    
    <ns0:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <ns0:property name="locations">
            <ns0:value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</ns0:value>
        </ns0:property>
    </ns0:bean>

   
    <ns0:bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery" lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </ns0:bean>

    
        <broker brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
```

Sorry for the long post , help would be appreciated !

Using latest Python version btw. Backwards compatibility not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "f string". Load the file to string, replace what is needed (see below) and save it again. Note that I changed `activemq.conf` to `activemq_conf`

```
activemq_conf = '/nfs'
data = f'''<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq_conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>'''
```

Comment: Hey balderman , i appreciate your attempt to answer my issue , it seems this is indeed a way to try and resolve my issue , ill report back if i had any problems.

Comment: @M4CHINE Great. Let me know.

Comment: Hey balderman , i ended up switching to lxml to resolve this issue.